# controlling some RGB LED modules with HD74HC254P and 74HC595N ICs

Tags: shift-register, led-matrix, documentation

I got some LED modules dismantled from old festival screen. It would be nice to get them working, but I can't find any info about them, neither I have any idea how to controll them. AFAIK they are made to be used in series on some bus, and each module has level shifter and 4 octal bus transceivers.

Each module is 16x16 pixels, 1 pixels is 4 LEDs (RRGB). But I can't figure out how to drive this thing. Each module is internally splitted into two 16x8 pixels module and each of these has 6 ICs (4x HD74HC245P (octal bus transceiver), HD74HC04P(hex inverter) and 74HC595N(shift register)).
There are also 12-pin connectors (one for in, one for out that connects to the next module, propably made for bunch of modules in series), 1 is GND, the rest 11 are data. It has only label saying P/N 5ml0341122 (which was not found by Google) and "KS-341 Ver1.2" written on PCB

I was not able to find any documentation to this on the internet.  Is there anybody who knows something about these modules?
Thanks.
Some pictures of them: https://photos.app.goo.gl/PH6HjkzokVJ7ovn49

//EDIT: I started to peel off the rubber that covers the LEDs side of PCB. There is one TB62705C for every 8 LEDs. Still had no idea how to drive these, but I think I'm getting close.

Comment: Do we assume that this was dismantled before any wiring or circuit layouts were taken - photos even?

Comment: I dont know anything about it. I just got the box with them and I was told that they were part of a big festival screen.

Comment: I was once in a similar situation with some panels of flip-dot displays. We traced out the connections from the logic chips to the connectors to figure out the interface, and then displayed some patterns to see how the data has to be arranged. It took some time, but if you have enough of the panels it may be worth it. Good luck!

Comment: @MarcoZollinger the PCB is covered by some rubber from one side, so I can see only one side of it, which makes tracing it pretty hard.

Comment: Then you would have to trace it with a multimeter, but it's gonna take some time. I think it's strange that there should be only one 8-bit shift register (and no latches) for a 16x8 pixel module? The 16 is probably done via 1:16 multiplexing, but for four colors, wouldn't you need to hold 4colors * 8pixels = 32bits in a latch or shift register? Or are they even multiplexing the colors?

Comment: @MarcoZollinger I found some more shift registers, there is one for each 8 LEDs, see edited question.

Comment: Ah, that does make more sense. I guess you found the TB62705 datasheet. I would probably try to trace where these LED drivers get their serial data from, working backwards from the LEDs to the connector.

Comment: @MarcoZollinger I think these panels draw too much current to just keep LEDs on, plus simple latching won't give you many colors. Most likely they are driven by PWM to get colors mixed in different proportions.

Comment: @Maple You are right, usually not all LEDs are kept on, but f.e. the column is multiplexed and one row at the time is on. It is difficult to do multiplexing and PWM at the same time, so many of these driver chips have 8-bit or 12-bit adjustable current outputs instead of PWM.

Comment: @MarcoZollinger Ah, that's where TB62705 comes into play.

Comment: Hmm, it seems though the TB62705 can not adjust its constant current output... I did a LED-matrix project that used the TLC5941 that could do what I described above.

Answer (score 0):

These look awfully similar to the ones in [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/383997/). Could be different model by the same manufacturer.

Here is [interface description](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/32x16-32x32-rgb-led-matrix.pdf) by Adafruit and [great tutorial](https://bikerglen.com/projects/lighting/led-panel-1up/). Note that functional description in that tutorial refers to many components you've found on your panels. The controlling mechanism could be the same.